# How to localize routes of a custom controller in shopware6

Tags: shopware

I'm following the guides of creating an custom controller.
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-controller

It works fine so far, but how do I localize a path to the controller?
I peeked into the symfony documentation about routing and found the solution by Annotation
https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n.
But this doesn't work. No mater how I formated my language string.

```
/**
     * @Route({
     *     "en-GB": "/joe",
     *     "de-DE": "/peter",
     *     "en-GB": "/joe",
     *     "de-DE": "/peter",
     *     "en": "/joe",
     *     "de": "/peter"
     * }, name="frontend.example.example", methods={"GET"})
     */
```

Comment: Not sure if that is even possible like this in Shopware, what is your use-case?

Comment: I would like to create a page with the custom controller under a route which is different in english and german.

Comment: You could create the action twice as a workaround if it's only those two languages, if it's for more a general use case I think it would be best to let the admin choose via config for the languages in the store.

Comment: Yes that could be a solution, honestly I didn't knew that it's such a big deal with localized paths. Anyway, thank you for the suggestions I think about an alternative solution/workaround.

Comment: Maybe it works, and somebody has a better answer:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not recommended in the way you are trying it.

Shopware can be configured in all kind of languages by the store owner. So it would not make sense to just hard code German and English language by in the code.

Instead, I suggest to write a custom router which picks up the route name from a plugin configuration, which then should allow to set the route name per language with a translatable entity. This is similar how products work: The store owner can configure a product in German as "Kissen" and English and "Pillow" and so the localized routes will work.

Answer (score 0):

Shopware is based on Symfony, so the discussed solution should work, and is sufficient for limited internationalization. E.g. If you only need to support a few languages.

I just tested this myself and it works to some extent in **Shopware 6.4.20.2**.

However, if a certain route was the same for two different localizations, only one of the routes would register properly. E.g. This will **not** work:

```
/**
 * @Route({"da-DK": "/kundeservice", "nb-NO": "/kundeservice" "en-US": "/support"}, name="frontend.support.page", methods={"GET"})
 */
```

Note the route is the same for both `da-DK` and `nb-NO`, and this will therefore not work properly, because it will "collapse" somehow and give you the wrong locale if you do `$request->getLocale()` later.

An easier way is to define the routes in the `routes.xml` of your plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
        https://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="supportPage" controller="nameOfPlugin\Storefront\Controller\supportPageController::supportPage" methods="GET|HEAD">
       <path locale="da-DK">/kundeservice</path>
       <path locale="nb-NO">/kundeservice</path>
       <path locale="en-US">/support</path>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Note. The `da-DK` and `nb-NO` translations are duplicated, and the route locale will be collapsed/overwritten, so it is not accurate in PHP. That's why you might want to include the **host name** too!

In addition, if your localization is domain name specific, you will for example be able to access the **English** URL on the **Danish** domain; this is a small issue, but it should not be possible, and it can lead to duplicated content in search engines.

To fix both problems, you got to associate the routes with the specific **host name** rather than just the locale.

Create seperate `route´ elements for each domain. E.g:

```
<route id="supportPage" controller="nameOfPlugin\Storefront\Controller\supportPageController::supportPage" methods="GET|HEAD" host="da.example.com">
  <path locale="da-DK">/kundeservice</path>
</route>

<route id="supportPage" controller="nameOfPlugin\Storefront\Controller\supportPageController::supportPage" methods="GET|HEAD" host="no.example.com">
  <path locale="nb-NO">/kundeservice</path>
</route>
```

If you need to fetch the locale you defined in `routes.xml` from *PHP* you can do it like this:

```
echo $request->getLocale();exit();
```